How long would it take to get from the port of Riga to London by boat in the 1890s?
My grandfather made a journey as a very young man from Latvia (Kurzeme) to London in the 1890s and I'm trying to figure out how he did it. I think he must have boarded a ship in Riga and I’m wondering how long that took and what sort of a ship it would have been.

Options to dig deeper: http://oceania.pbworks.com/w/page/8473317/UK%20Bailey%20Leetham is one shipping line to Baltic ports at the time, as was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Wilson_Sons_%26_Co. Likely a variety of other shipping companies.

A UK parliamentary record on "alien traffic" from 1911 states that the "United Shipping Company" ran ships between Libau (now Liepāja, Latvia) and London, discharging their passengers at Hay’s Wharf or Millwall Docks. Not quite the right time frame but may be worth following up on.

Re travel time: The Board of Trade Journal, Vol. 8, No. 42, Jan. 1890, p. 280: "A weekly service will be established between Libau and London; the boats leaving the first named port every Wednesday and the latter every Friday. The time occupied in going and returning between the two ports will be 8½ days. The passenger cabins will be thoroughly adapted for the comfort and convenience of passengers and electric lighting fitted throughout the vessels."

I know that Finnish people emigrating to North America generally went via Sweden, taking a ship from Gothenburg to Hull, which seems to have been a common port in the UK for ships from Scandinavia and the Baltic. After that they took a train to Liverpool or Southampton to board ships to America, so a ship from the Baltic sea to Hull and a train to London seems like a possibility. See for example the map on page 10 here: https://siirtolaisuusinstituutti.fi/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/how-to-trace-your-roots-in-finland-r.pdf

@Dronir Thanks for bringing up Hull: London Statistics, 1894-95, Vol. 5, p. xiv shows that all aliens from Russia en route to America or other non-UK destinations arrived at Hull. OP may want to double check the assumption of London arrival.

My initial thought was: Taking a direct ship, if such a connection existed, would have been a strange choice, as it would take at least three more days than combining ships and trains on different legs of the route. But it turns out there are special circumstances at work.
At first, let's take a look at the main obstacle on route: Jutland. To get from the western end of the Baltic sea to the North sea, there are three variants:

a ship running around Jutland through the Skagerrak. This would have taken two to three days, depending on the time of the year in extremely stormy conditions.

passage on a boat through a canal connecting the two seas. Before 1895, this would have been the Eider canal on a towboat, with a passage time of three days. After that, the new Nord-Ostsee-Kanal (Kiel canal) might have shortened that time to less than a day, but I doubt there would have been many opportunities for passengers, as most of the traffic was geared towards transporting goods.

taking a train. For example, the Lübeck-Hamburg railway connected the two port cities in one and a half hours.


I thought the rational choice was clear: just take the train.
I took into account several variants of travel: by ship from Riga to Stettin, Lübeck or Kiel, on to Hamburg or Bremen by train, and by ship from there to London.
Or by train from Riga to Berlin, and then to Hamburg or Bremen. Or taking a train all the way to Oostende or Calais, and only taking a ferry to cross the Channel.
The fastest possible connection I found would be by train, according to the Reichs-Kursbuch. 1890: make a start in Riga in the evening (8:35 PM), change trains in Moscheiken (Mažeikiai) in the middle of the night and Koschedary (Kaišiadorys) around midday, reaching Eydtkuhnen in the afternoon (4:20 PM). Then take a night train to Berlin (6:12 PM) that reaches Berlin in the morning of the next day (6:11 AM Schlesischer Bahnhof). If you are willing to press on directly, you could take the next direct train to Oostende via Mechelen (8:00 AM) and be there the next morning (5:24 AM). After crossing the Channel a train leaves Dover (9:30 AM) and reaches London around midday (12:20 PM). That makes a total time of 64 hours.
The Kursbuch also lists prices. A second class ticket from Riga to the German border would have cost 13.93 Rubel, or at a (listed) exchange rate of 2.23, 31.07 Reichsmark. The leg to Berlin would have been 49.80 Reichsmark. A sleeper would have been 10 Reichsmark extra. Berlin to London is listed as 79.20 Reichsmark, making a total of 170.07 Reichsmark or 76.26 Rubels.

But most of these variants have to be thrown out of the window. In 1892, a Cholera epidemic hit Hamburg. It was assumed to be caused by Eastern European migrants, on transit through Germany on their way to America.
As a reaction, Germany more or less closed its borders to Russia for migrants. It took until 1894 before it was opened again, but under a strict quarantine regime that lasted until 1914. At the border, migrants had to pass through desinfection and inspection barracks, and then were isolated in charter trains. Only a handfull of routes through Germany were allowed:

All trains from Russia passed through Berlin-Ruhleben, and all of them went on to either Hamburg or Bremerhaven, where travellers would be transfered on board of their ships immediately. For this to work, the migrants effectively had to book a combined rail and ship ticket all the way from Russia to England.
I have no idea how much time traveling would take including all these inspections, and what it would cost. But it would not have been comfortable, and avoiding the hassle on a direct ship might have been a good choice, even if travel time was longer.
The British health inspection regime, by the way, was much more geared towards controling the health and the hygiene of immigrants. They were basically not stopped from entering the country, provided they were not considered to be "filthy". More about this can be found in

Christiane Reinecke: Grenzen der Freizügigkeit. Migrationskontrolle in Großbritannien und Deutschland, 1880-1930. Ouldenbourg 2010. Chapter 2: Zur Abwehr fremder Körper: Die Gesundheitskontrollen an den Grenzen


What I like about this answer is that it (IMHO correctly) points out that someone shooting for speed wouldn't have taken a boat for legs that trains are available. That of course implies something else (likely cost) was a more important deciding factor for the itenerary, which gets us back into "We don't know, because said person isn't optimizing for speed." Still, the bit at the end that tries to establish a lower bound is useful too.

I tried figuring out how much that Reichmark total is in today's $. Best I can find is a 1913 exchange rate of 4.2-1. A US inflation calculator gives me 1913-today as 1-31.8. Which means that would have cost somewhere in the neighborhood of $1,150 in today's money. Probably way wrong, but may work as a ballpark.

Re "I think the choice is clear: just take the train." For someone from the Russian Empire, wouldn't this have required a transit visa, at least for Prussia? If so, how easy was it to acquire such a visa and at what cost?

@njuffa Visa were not generally needed in Europe before WWI. But another factor seems to be crucial: In 1892, after the cholera breakout in Hamburg, the borders to Russia were first more or less closed, and from 1894 until 1914, transit migrants had to pass a quaratine regime that meant they a) had to present ship tickets for leaving the country in Hamburg or Bremen and b) were isolated in special charter trains and transit barracks. So regular train schedules or routes via Belgium might have been impossible. https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1524/9783486707601.34/html

@T.E.D. Comparing a 1913 price to a modern price is very tricky because the ratio of different item prices to each other will have changed dramatically. If you convert the 1913 price into say kilograms of bread and back to modern dollars you might get a very different answer than if you convert to say pairs of mens trousers. If you use minutes of an inner city telephone call you are way out.

@quarague - Yeah, I was tempted to look up the price of eggs in Germany in 1890 as a further sanity check, but that's way more effort than I'm willing to put into simple comments. I don't know that the value given is "correct", but it ought to be close enough to give the idea that poverty-stricken hopeful emigre would have trouble coming up with it, which was the point of the exercise.

@T.E.D. Perchance I can name the price of domestic coal in Königsberg before the war: 1.40 Mark for a Zentner (hundredweight). Since this was mainly coal imported from Britain (Scotland, Yorkshire and Derbyshire), prices would not have been that different on the Russian side. My guess is that for around 30 Zentner = 42 Mark, you could heat a small family home during one winter season. (The chance in this is that my grandfather wrote his dissertation in 1923 about coal trade in Eastern Prussia.)

I'd think coal is one product that is definitely needed and used for far different things than it was in 1890. That's why we prefer to look at eggs or loaves of bread (still not perfect, because fewer people cook at home anymore).

(a gallon of milk is often used too, but I personally don't like that one, because 65% of humanity can't digest it).

I'm not sure we can know that without more information.
It looks like today if you combine trains and boat travel it can be about 4 days, with a couple of nights sleeping through layovers. Of course if you happened to have a ship that was just making the trip straight it would be far quicker. It's quite possible they had those, if a lot of people were wanting to make that trip at the time. Cars weren't really available an option, and the rail networks were just getting built up, so there was likely a lot more passenger boat travel available.
OTOH, a good express trip may have been much more expensive. So someone looking to immigrate for better financial opportunities may have taken the cheapest available, which could mean multiple port stops, or even a multi-carrier constructed trip like the one linked above.

The complete route is 1300 seamiles around Jutland, or 1000 seamiles through the Kiel Canal (opened in 1895). How do you propose to travel that far on a ship "far quicker than" four days, if the steamers of the time could make around 300 seamiles per day on open sea?)

@ccprog - Didn't say that. The sentence you are quoting was responding to a sentence talking about the present day. Obviously that relation would hold true for 1890 as well, but you'd have to work out how long one or the other would have taken. Sadly, there's no convenient record for trans-Baltic passages like there was for the Atlantic. The point though was there's going to be a huge range in how long it would have taken a traveler.

The Baltic today has particularly poor international train connections, so it's not surprising that 130 years ago it would have been faster than today.

Are there any actual memoirs (not novels or stories) of Litvak Jews in your local London Jewish Museums at all ?
Shipping anything is far cheaper than sending it by train. It's possible that regular freighters may have been carrying individual men (as opposed to women, children or families) if they were willing to pay and/or work their passage.
Look through registers for those shipping lines working the Baltic routes.
